# Where is this construct augmentation section I remember?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, books, content-identification, constructs

I've looked through a bunch of books and pdfs and cannot find a very specific section that exists in one of them detailing new types of purchasable/buildable alterations for a construct.

Specifically the section had an option for a cockpit so you could pilot your construct like a mech as long as it is at least one size category larger than you. I also recall the same section had another augmentation which transformed the chest cavity into a storage space.

Where can I find this particular augmentation and the section it was in? It could be within 1st or 3rd party books or possibly either Dungeon or Dragon Magazine.

Comment: *Actual* piloting, huh? Not merging with the golem and operating it with one's mind or spirit, but, like, making the golem go by climbing inside and pulling levers and pushing buttons and stuff? Is that accurate?

Comment: @HeyICanChan Yes. Precisely. If it helps, the same section had another augmentation which transformed the chest cavity into a storage space.

Comment: @Sonkuragari Added that to the question as well. Any information you remember may help

Answer (score 3):

The closest thing that rings my bell is

## d20 Mecha Compendium

ISBN: 1894814800 or 978-1894814805 or 1894814924

From the back cover:

> From epic magical fantasy to the high tech far future, the D20 Mecha Compendium brings the mechanized action genre to life with eleven adventure settings, all complete with world background, campign ideas and pre-designed machines. This book is an essential companion to the d20 Game Master!
>
> The d20 Mecha Compendium delivers the firepower and strength that players need to deal with those awkward situations where the party is running for their lives. Control a towering magical knight that can go toe-to-toe with dragons, a transformable superpowered aerofighter, or anything in-between!
>
> The d20 Mecha Compendium holds nearly a hundred mecha designs and variants from a variety of game worlds spanning several genres, from magical fantasy to space opera by way of the modern day. In addition to brand new, never-seen-before designs, the book contains 3rd edition game statistics for Heavy Gear, Jovian Chronicles and Gear Krieg mecha! Game Masters and players alike will find the d20 Mecha Compendium an indispensible aid in populating their campaigns.

- 3rd edition compatible - check
- fantasy settings - check
- option for a cockpit - check
- pilot your construct like a mech - **exactly** mech
- chest cavity storage space - kinda:

  > most battlesults thus include some sort of cargo storage or carrying
  > capacity
- augmenting constructs - *mecha points*, so kinda check

Comment: Meta-note - it is available on the Internet for free, but probably illegal, so I will not link to it.

Comment: I believe [this](https://www.dmsguild.com/product/1106/d20-Mecha-Compendium-Deluxe-Edition) may be a legal link to the product

Comment: Thanks. However, the section I was referring to was definitely a construct related section within a more general book. The whole book wasn't about mecha. I'll try to find a copy and look through it but this is definitely not the particular thing I was looking for. Thank you all the same though.

Comment: @Sonkuragari good luck with your search, then. This book met your description so well I decided to post it, and hope it can be useful even if it is not exactly the same thing you were looking for.

Comment: @Mołot it definitely looks helpful and if I can get my hands on a copy I probably will. It might be helpful in general so I appreciate it being brought to my attention.

Answer (score 3):

I found another possibility.

## Pathfinder Roleplaying Game: Ultimate Magic

ISBN-10: 1601252994

ISBN-13: 978-1601252999

Definitely has the piloting part. Here's an excerpt of that modification.

> This modification allows the construct to be worn like armor by its creator. So long as the creator wears it, the construct performs no independent actions, remaining under the control of the creator, and any attacks directed at the wearer first damage the construct.

I couldn't find anything about a storage compartment, but there was a Shatter Stash modification.

> For this subcategory of complex modification, parts of the golem are made with hollowed sections carved from deliberately weaker materials, designed to shatter when struck by attackers.

The attacker that breaks the shatter stash then suffers from a trap that's released from inside it.

Hope this helps.

Comment: That first part sounds really really familiar. I might've been looking at Pathfinder stuff without thinking about it.  I'll definitely have to check this out. Thanks!